# Abaqus script measure/calculate surface area

Tags: python, scripting, surface, abaqus

Is there a way to measure/calculate the surface area of a generated model with `abaqus`?

I'm familiar with *Tools -> Query... -> Mass properties* in `abaqus CAE` or the scripting version:

```
from abaqus import *
prop=mdb.models['Model'].rootAssembly.getMassProperties()
```

However, I cannot find an equal command for surface area.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I have written a plugin to do this. Let me know if you want it and I'll host the files on my Google drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `getArea()` returns the surface area of a set of faces.

For example:

```
a = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
a.getArea(a.instances['Part-1-1'].faces)
```

This also works for volume with the command `getVolume()`

```
a.getVolume()
```

and it works for parts as such:

```
p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1']
p.getArea(p.faces)
p.getVolume()
```

I highly recommend to use the `Abaqus Scripting Reference Guide`, which can be found here:

[Abaqus Scripting Reference Guide](http://50.16.225.63/v2016/books/ker/default.htm)

**Edit:** This method counts internal faces aswell when you partition the part. In that case, you would have to pick the faces on the surface yourself for example with the `findAt()` function.

Comment: I'm thinking if the instance is partitioned this might count the internal faces.  Sorry to be vague, but you might want to validate that.

Comment: You're right. I checked and it does count the internal faces aswell when you partition the part.