# Abaqus Script Measuring Surface Area/ Volume

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus

The answer to the following question has already been posted as follows:
[Question previously asked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f96U.png): [Abaqus script measure/calculate surface area](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36423255/1004168)
The answer to it as follows:[Answer provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agGIN.png)
however on implementing it I get following error:

```
******AttributeError: 'Part' object has no attribute 'getVolume****'"**
```

Now on going through Abaqus Scripting user guide I saw that `getVolume()` and `getArea()` are attributes of Part object. Still, the error. Any ideas where am I going wrong?

Edit:The attributes provided exist only for a MdB and not odb hence the Problem.Also, I was not able to get the instances in MdB because I was using an Output database file(from a .inp file and not .cae) and it included no instances in MdB. I hope this helps.If you use a .cae file you would get instances having some value and not empty and then it is easy to compute the volume and area.

Comment: a version issue maybe? an actual link to the previous question would be good.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36423255/1004168

Comment: @ agentp I think that it is not a version issue,as I tried performing the same set of commands on a previous Version with same Inputs and I get the same result..:( .I think there is something wrong in what I am  doing.Thanks for the link though..;)

Comment: what is the actual code you used to get this error?  The fact that it's looking for an "attribute" `getVolume` instead of a "method" `getVolume()` makes me think you maybe dropped the parentheses?

Comment: @DanielF:Nope I included them.I might be out on a limb here but I think the 'part' object is different in different cases and so are ist atttribute.Some reading through object accessability makes me believe so.I may be wrong about it.Following is the link for it:http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.13/books/cmd/default.htm?startat=pt02ch06s01.html

Comment: Well there's no way for us to tell what the problem is without any code to do go by.  Please try to give a [mcve] so we can replicate the error.

Comment: >>> from abaqus import *
>>> from abaqusConstants import *
>>> import __main__
>>> import visualization
>>> myViewport = session.Viewport(name='Beam')
>>> odbPath = 'X:\work\mulyea\New\Job-1.odb'
>>> myOdb =  session.openOdb(name=odbPath, readOnly=False)
>>> myViewport.setValues(displayedObject=myOdb) 
>>> myOdb.parts
session.openOdb(r'X:/work/mulyea/New/Job-1.odb').parts
>>> myOdb.parts.getVolume()
AttributeError: 'Repository' object has no attribute 'getVolume'

Comment: Sorry I can't attach a snap as I dont have Requisite reps to add one more snap.:(

Comment: edit the code into the question. too hard to read code in comments.

Comment: near as i can tell squinting at that you are referencing the whole list of parts, not just one.

Comment: Now that the actual code and correct error has been shown (please put it into the question!), I agree with @agentp. An Abaqus Repository is similar to a Python dictionary. The `getVolume` method applies to a Part object contained within the Repository.  Use a loop and sum the output from each Part, if that's what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

For volume measurement, you may use command like this (tested on Abaqus 6.14-5).

```
volume_element=session.xyDataListFromField(odb=odb, outputPosition=WHOLE_ELEMENT, variable=(('EVOL', WHOLE_ELEMENT), ), elementSets=('PART-1.SET-1'))
```

You can then access your volume value using :

```
volume_element[i].data[1][1]
```

Hope it will help you!